# Turn server webrtc configuration assistance

Tags: configuration, centos, webrtc, bitcoin, rfc5766turnserver

I am in the process of configuring a TURN server to work with SimpleRTC on CentOS6(I think).

This is the first time I am building webrtc services on centos.  I have successfully installed this service on Ubuntu 64 bit Amazon EC2 instance.  Unfortunately centos installation is a bit different, and I am slightly lost.

I have the Turn service installed and running.  When navigating to my ip and listening port in the url, I see that my turn service is listening on that ip and port with this message from turnserver running -v flag.

445: IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: 173.57.xxx.xx:55676
445: IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: 173.57.xxx.xx:55677

The HTML of the page displays this message...
TURN Server

I am fairly certain that turnserver is setup properly because of this, but I think the ice connections are somehow screwed up.

Here is my ICE config.

This configuration resides in... latest.js, simplewebrtc.bundle.js, and simplewebrtc.js

```
{iceServers:[{url:"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
    {    
    'url': 'turn:mrturn@23.235.xxx.xxx:5349?transport=udp',    
    'credential': 'xxxxx'/*,    
    'username': 'mrturn:xxxxx'*/    
    },    
    {    
    'url': 'turn:mrturn@23.235.xxx.xxx:5349?transport=tcp',    
    'credential': 'xxxx'/*,    
    'username': 'mrturn:xxxx'*/    
    }]}
```

I have tried quite a few things here, but I cannot get the turn server to give any indication as to why this is not connecting.  Obviously it would need to try and connect for some debugging to occur via turn server command line, but I just can't get there.

If anyone has any advice as to why this connection is not working please let me know.  I will tip in bitcoin to any answer that resolves this issue.

Comment: Not sure what happened here.  But somehow my port 3478 is open now and turn server is listening.  Thanks for the help guys.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ports are open on your server (both TCP and UDP)

TURN runs on the same ports as STUN: 3478 for TURN over UDP and TCP, and 5349 for TURN over TLS.  However, TURN has its own set of Service Record (SRV) names: "turn" for UDP and TCP, and
"turns" for TLS.

So maybe try

```
{iceServers:[{url:"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
    {    
    'url': 'turns:mrturn@23.235.xxx.xxx:5349?transport=udp',    
    'credential': 'xxxxx'/*,    
    'username': 'mrturn:xxxxx'*/    
    },    
    {    
    'url': 'turns:mrturn@23.235.xxx.xxx:5349?transport=tcp',    
    'credential': 'xxxx'/*,    
    'username': 'mrturn:xxxx'*/    
    }]}
```

If that doesn't work, maybe you can try to have the TURN server listen on 3478 (its default port).

hope this helps

Also the [RFC5766-TURN-server](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/turn-server-project-rfc5766-turn-server) group is a great place for questions regarding this project and usually answer pretty fast

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.  I have tried using the default port 3478, but I cannot seem to connect to the port.

When running on 3478 I get a message stating that the socket is in use.  But when I check my open sockets using open port tool.  It says that 3478 is closed(this socket is open, but there is not a process listening here)

Answer (score 0):

late, but try to put your turn service conf @ first position in the iceServers arr, as noted here: https://bloggeek.me/popexpert-interview/